# document within both Pro and Acrobat Reader

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-acrobat

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro 7 for Windows XP.  How do I go about making our PDFs read only and Enable Commenting so that once saved users are unable to modify the PDF content but are still able to add Comments (annotations) to the document within both Pro and Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score 0):

If they are read-only, by definition they will not be able to accept comments. Read-only is a file setting that prevents the file from being modified or written to in any way. Commenting requires saving the comments, which requires writing to the file, which precludes the possibility of this setup working.

You should check the various protection settings in Acrobat Pro to see if there is a security setting that prevents modification of the content of the document, but allows the saving of comments.